# Submit Form in Vex Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am building a Website in Material Design and when the user clicks on the button for a new post, a PopUp opens (managed by Vex) on which the User can enter some text, add a file and when he clicks on "Go" the file and message shall be pushed via method=post to another file.

Problem: Vex puts a Form on top of everything so I am not sure how to submit all the data to my fnc_create_post.php file. I tried to manipulate the form outside with adding a method, action and enctype but it can't push the files.

```
$('#new-post').on('click', function(){
        vex.dialog.open({
          message: '<b>Neuer Beitrag</b>',
          input: '<input type="hidden" name="classid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><div class="create-post input-field"><textarea name="message" style="min-height:100px" placeholder="Erstellen Sie hier Ihre Nachricht..."></textarea><div class="file-field input-field" style="display:none;"><div class="btn"><span><i class="mdi-editor-attach-file"></i></span><input name="file" id="file" type="file" /></div><div class="file-description"><i class="mdi-hardware-keyboard-arrow-left"></i> Optional Datei hinzufügen</div><div class="remove-file"><i class="mdi-action-highlight-remove small"></i></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></div><input type="submit" style="display:none;" />',
          afterOpen: function($vexContent) {
            $('form.vex-dialog-form').attr('action', 'fnc/create_post.php').attr('method', 'POST').attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
          },
          onSubmit: function(e) {

          }
        });
    });
```

How do I fix that? Push everything via Ajax? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: do you find your `<input type="file"..` among this?